# Adding objects containing characters to a list R

Tags: r, list, object, environment-variables

I have multiple lists beginning with "hello" saved in the global environment. e.g.

```
hello_List1
    chr "hello1"
    chr "hello2"

hello_List2
    chr "hello1234"
    chr "hello24"
```

I want to create a list of the values of all the object lists that begin with "hello"

e.g. I want this to form

```
listName
   chr "hello1"
   chr "hello2"
   chr "hello1234"
   chr "hello24"
```

please give me guidance on how to go about doing this

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
lst <- mget(grep('hello', ls(), value = TRUE), envir = globalenv()) 
do.call('rbind', unlist(lst, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE))
     [,1]      
[1,] "hello1"  
[2,] "hello2"  
[3,] "hello234"
[4,] "hello24"
```

Comment: this is perfect thanks, just added as.list(...) to make it a list

Comment: If you need the output as a list then no need for `do.call`, just do `unlist(lst, recursive = FALSE)`